# React Native - Trouble Setting Up Azure Authentication

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo

To start off, this is my first React Native application and I am trying to connect it to Azure for logging in. I have used it in a MAUI project so I know that my Azure settings are all set up correctly. The library that I am using is `react-native-app-auth` and I have been following the implementation steps from the examples in the repo here: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/main/Example/App.js

When I click on the button to load Azure up for logging in, I am console logging the error in a try/catch and it says `Cannot read property 'authorize' of null`. I am using Expo to test my application.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { authorize, prefetchConfiguration } from 'react-native-app-auth';
import Constants from './Constants';
import Tabs from './navigation/tabs';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const defaultAuthState = {
  hasLoggedInOnce: false,
  provider: '',
  accessToken: '',
  accessTokenExpirationDate: '',
  refreshToken: '',
};

export default App = () => {

  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(defaultAuthState);
  useEffect(() => {
    prefetchConfiguration({
      warmAndPrefetchChrome: true,
      connectionTimeoutSeconds: 5,
      ...Constants.config,
    });
  }, []);

  const handleAuthorize = useCallback(
    async () => {
      try {
        const config = Constants.config;
        const newAuthState = await authorize({
          ...config,
          connectionTimeoutSeconds: 5,
          iosPrefersEphemeralSession: true
        });

        setAuthState({
          hasLoggedInOnce: true,
          provider: provider,
          ...newAuthState,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Failed to log in', error.message);
      }
    },
    [authState],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Button onPress={handleAuthorize} title="Login with Azure" />
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am not sure why it seems to be saying that authorize is null when I am following the same steps as others that I have found...

Constants.config contains all of the correct attributes that are found in the examples but using the values respectively to my needs.